# TimeUnit Java returning zero days

Tags: java, date, calendar, java-11

Hi wanted to get the number of days in between dates.

Below is the logic I tried

```
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
final Date endDate = cal.getTime();
final Date currentDate = new Date();
System.out.println(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(endDate.getTime() - currentDate.getTime()));
```

It is always printing 0. Expectation is to print 1.
Any ideas?

Comment: Side note: Please avoid the outdated (pun intended, sorry) `java.util.Date` and `Calendar` classes. They have a lot of known issues and have been replaced by the classes in the [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package.

Comment: I changed to java.time and it is working as expected thanks

Comment: Both, `endDate` and `currentDate` should use the same base i.e. it should be `final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
final Date currentDate = cal.getTime();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
final Date endDate = cal.getTime();`

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead since Java 8 use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1):

A day is `24*60*60*1000` milliseconds.

`endDate.getTime() - currentDate.getTime()` is always shorter than that.

So you should always add 1 to the result:

```
System.out.println(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(endDate.getTime() - currentDate.getTime()) + 1);
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. Check the correct answer in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69735028/timeunit-java-returning-zero-days#comment123264038_69735028).

Comment: *A day is `24*60*60*1000` milliseconds.* Incorrect. A day may be longer or shorter than 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

The result of `endDate.getTime() - currentDate.getTime()` is just a few millisecond less than a day, so the result is rounded to 0.

You would have the expected result if you initialize your calendar with the currentDate:

```
final Date currentDate = new Date();
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(currentDate);
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
final Date endDate = cal.getTime();
System.out.println(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(endDate.getTime() - currentDate.getTime()));
```